# Is it possible to distinguish escape sequences in lexer in Antlr4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I would like to match sequences like `\'` and `\"` as lexer elements

```
ESCAPESEQUECE :
  '\\\"' |
  '\\\'' 
  ;
```

while also distinguish individual quotes when they are not escaped

```
SINGLEQUOTE:
   '\''
   ;

DOUBLEQUOTE:
   '\"'
   ;
```

The final goal it to recognize MySQL like strings with parser.

Is this possible / correct way?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with thtis and what is not working with your given grammar?

Comment: @BartKiers what are "normal" string literals? MySQL ones look pretty normal for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

Yes, it is totally possible by having separate tokens.

### Example

```
grammar escp;

SINGLE: '\'';
DOUBLE: '\"';
ESCAPED : '\\"' | '\\\'';

char: SINGLE | DOUBLE;
escaped : ESCAPED;

program: (char | escaped)+;
```

The AST for input string `'\"'"\"""'\'\"\'` will be:

[image]

Comment: @BartKiers as a good practice. In this case it doesn't matter because the tokens' prefixes are different. But in the case of the same prefixes and different suffixes the tokens sequence matters.

Comment: Why do you name single tokens "more specialized"? It seems to me that they are less specialized? Do more complext expressions have precedence in Antlr?

Comment: @Dims yes, you are right it should be the opposite :) Yes. the sequence of tokens definitions might alter the lexer phase.